# UItableViewCell not the right size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Creating a .xib:

[image]

set the class:

[image]

This is how it shows:

[image]

Here is how I load the cell:

```
@implementation FieldInfoTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FieldInfoCell" bundle:nil];

    [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:FieldInfoCellIndentifier];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        FieldInfoCell *fieldCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FieldInfoCellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        fieldCell.fieldNameLabel.text = self.boundarier.name;

        return fieldCell;
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

FielcInfoCell:

```
@interface FieldInfoCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fieldNameLabel;

@end

@implementation FieldInfoCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

The label is being renamed, but the cell size and background color are not being set.

EDIT:

I set the height in IB:

[image]

added:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 150;
}
```

and that gives me the height, but still no background color. Kinda leads me to think I'm not setting something else correctly.

Comment: are you setting the cell height on the UITableView in IB? or in the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tableView row height from your UITableViewDelegate:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       return YOUR_HEIGHT;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't set the background color in the xib for a plain table view style (it does work for a grouped style table). You have to set the color in code in the tableView: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:173/255.0 green:75/255.0 blue:33/255.0 alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: @Log139, hmmm..., it did for me. What color are you seeing? White?

Comment: Sry, I commented on it before I realized it was in the method `tableView:willDisplayCell:ForRowAtIndexPath:`. This does indeed work, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cell height on the parent UITableView in the Interface Builder. The value must be the original (the smaller) value. Try setting this value to height you want to set it to.